# How to use the getSource method in Java?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I'm a beginner Programmer, i'm learning from a book. And i'm having trouble using the `getSource()` method in java. Please take a look at the code below, it's has plenty of comments to try to help you see what i'm thinking, and it's well written Thank You, and this is my first time using stackoverFlow.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class EventDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public EventDemo() //constructor
    {

        super("Sign in");    //title for JFrame

        setSize(300, 250);  //size for JFrame

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    // this make sure the JFrame close when click on exit

        JLabel username = new JLabel("Enter Username");  //promt user for username

        username.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));  //set the font for the username label

        JTextField usernameTextField = new JTextField(20);  // where user type in username

        JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter password"); // prompt user for password

        password.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); // set font for password label

        JTextField passwordTextField = new JTextField(20);  // where user enter password

        JButton login = new JButton("Login");    // login button created

        JButton back = new JButton("Back");   // back button

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());     // our layout      

        setVisible(true);   // making sure we see our frame when we run our program :) i know it's better to this in main   

        login.addActionListener(this);   // telling our login button to listen for an event
        back.addActionListener(this);  // telling our back button to listen for an event

        add(username); // adding components to frame, you guys know this :)
        add(usernameTextField);
        add(password);
        add(passwordTextField);
        add(login);
        add(back);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) // THIS IS WHERE I'M GOING CRAZY, INSIDE THE METHOD. i'm trying to see which button is causing the event. 
    {

        // this is the method the book (Java Programming Seventh Edition Joyce Farrell) taught me, and i also see this online as well, but is not working 
        Object source = x.getSource(); //no error shows up here

        if (source == login) // or if(x.getSource == login) // Eclipse is saying "login cannot be resolved to a variable"
        {
            // do this..
        } else {
            // to this.... it's only two buttons :)
        }

        // this method below i got online, but it works. But it said i have to set the buttons name after i created them see the first 4 line of code below
        JButton login = new JButton();
        JButton back = new JButton();
        login.setText("Login");
        back.setText("Back");
        // the above 4 line of code would go inside the constructor EventDemo, and not inside the actionPerformed method

        String source = x.getActionCommand();

        if (source.equals("login")) {
            // do this..
        } else {
            // do this...
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please work to improve your question. You'll want to do this since it will improve your chances of getting good answers quickly. My suggestions include: 1) don't put key information in code comments only, but instead take the time to type out a well-written and clear question, one with adequate background information. 2) Please put in the effort to post **well-formatted code**. If your code is all left justified, we can't read it well, and if we can't read it, we can't understand it. So learn about Java code formatting standards, including indentation standards, including when to include,...

Comment: ... and when to avoid empty lines. Your code above has no indentation whatsoever and gross over-use of blank lines making it very hard to follow.

Comment: In fact, if you indented your code correctly, you'd see instantly that you've got some serious variable scope problems -- your actionPerformed method is trying to get a reference to a variable that it can't see because the variable was declared within your class's constructor and is only visible within the constructor.

Comment: What trouble are you having, whats the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Eclipse is complaining "Login cannot be resolved" is because it expects a login variable that has not been declared. Your login variable declaration is inside the EventDemo constructor and is not available in the actionPerformed() method. If you move the declaration before the constructor and initialize inside the constructor, it should not complain any more.

```
public class EventDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   JButton login;



public EventDemo()   //constructor
{
//....
// do stuff

login = new JButton("Login");
// ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you So much, You guys are Heros. This Was was Starting to deter me from learning to code. I'm young and i'm still learning, i'm also a self Taught. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `JButton login;` in the class `EventDemo` (like globally) before the constructor. And then you can initialize it in the constructor. So that `login` can be accessed any where in your code.

Also, you happen to have declared `source` twice (`Object source = x.getSource();` and `String source = x.getActionCommand();`) so please notice that and change `String source = x.getActionCommand();` to `source = x.getActionCommand();`.

```
   public class EventDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        JButton login;

        public EventDemo() //constructor
        {
            //....
            // do stuff

            login = new JButton("Login");
            // ...

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) // THIS IS WHERE I'M GOING CRAZY, INSIDE THE METHOD. i'm trying to see which button is causing the event. 
        {
            //your code
            source = x.getActionCommand();//take out the String

            if (source.equals("login")) {
                // do this..
            } else {
                // do this...
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you So much, You guys are Heros. This Was was Starting to deter me from learning to code. I'm young and i'm still learning, i'm also a self Taught. THANKS!!

Comment: You are welcome @Mykey , don't forget to mark as best answer,  thank you